# sagepay not working after moving site

Tags: opayo

I am new to this magento and sagepay. I have tranfered my customers site from one server to another server. But customer's can't process the payments. On front end i am seeing this message when select sage pay payment method

An error occurred with Sage Pay:
4020 : Information received from an Invalid IP address.

I have added ip addresses at sage page but still not working. What ip address i need to add. Is this ip address of domain name?

Also when log in to magento control panel then if i click on Sage Page Dashboard then i see this error message
An error occurred: A valid  value is required. : teste :
I am doing this first time so no idea if this message on board is normal or i have done something wrong.

The site used to work fine on previous server. I have copied whole site to new server and rest everything works fine.

Any suggestion/idea will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you have root access to the server? If so, get the list of ip addresses from the ipv4 configuration on the network card, and make sure that they are all listed in your sagepay account. Make sure these are in your live sagepay account.

Answer (score 2):

Add your domain's ip in valid IP's list under settings tabs in your sage pay account